# Верстка: как уменьшить ширину между колонками?

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка, javascript, css

Товарищи, подскажите, как исправить проблему.
Есть сайт 
http://2.demo.seo-experts.com/local/templates/bilet/assets/izhstal/sektor11.html.
Мне надо уменьшить ширину между колонками (.col).

[image]

[image]

Когда я делаю `.col { width:15px;}`, то подсветка криво смотрится.
Как исправить?

Comment: Так не видать по вашей ссылке того, что на картинках, 404 кажет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так ёлки ж!
У вас в скрипте захардкожено:

```
$('.izhstal-sektor11-1_bg').css('background-position', 'left ' + (x*22) + 'px');
$('.izhstal-sektor11-2').css('background-position', 'right -10px top ' + (6+x*22) + 'px');
$('.izhstal-sektor11-3').css('background-position', 'right ' + (182-x*22) + 'px top');
```

Если уж хардкодить, то поменяйте 22 на 19 тогда.

Comment: `$('.izhstal-sektor11-3').css('background-position', 'right ' + (147-x*18) + 'px top');`

Это помогло. ) Если вам не трудно, можете объяснить, что означает этот код.

Comment: не трудно.
При наведении на элемент с классом row, diag или col, в x читается дата-атрибут num этого элемента.
Затем элементам с классами izhstal-sektor11-1_bg, izhstal-sektor11-2 и izhstal-sektor11-3 устанавливается свойство css background-position в зависимости от полученного значения. Везде это значение вычисляется из x*22, где 22 (теперь уже 18) - просто коэффициент, равный ширине колонки вместе с отступом.
При уведении же мыши фон средствами css прячется настолько далеко за пределами экрана, что увидеть его можно будет только на следующей модели аймака.

Comment: япрекрасно. ) И еще один вопросик: как избежать, чтобы всплывающее окошко не заходило вниз дивов  
http://joxi.ru/752aQpW6Tg7P20  
http://2.demo.seo-experts.com/local/templates/bilet/assets/izhstal/sektor5.html
______
Всю ночь сижу, запарился. ( Помогите мне, пожалуйста.  
у меня сейчас izhstal-sektor11-3 нормально показывается, но izhstal-sektor11-2 подсветка не совпадает. Как можно исправить?  
http://test.webjay.ru

Comment: А не надо ночами сидеть. :) С утра голова свежее. И не надо секторам разные z-index давать. При наведении только дать больший z-index, тогда и будет всплывашка показываться поверх всего остального.